# Page using Facebook php sdk to invite friend of user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, invitation

I am developing a web site which uses facebook php sdk to login user and i want to send an invitation to join the site to a facebook friend he interacts with in my site. I know the fb user id he interacts so i want to send an invitations to him via facebook php sdk.

Any ideas or sample code? I don't want the user to select the user he invites i already know who is the user i should dend the request.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Do you want to send request to visit your site to particular friend of the user who came to your site ?

Comment: My user selects to apply an action to one of his fb friends. In order to see what was his action i must send a notification/invitation to that particular friend. e.g. your friend George said something for you. Go here to see what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For notifying the friend of the user to ask him to interact with your website you can utilize the [apprequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#requests).

Comment: Thanks! After so much googling how i didn't see this page?